# How to send http request through proxy server in swift programming

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, proxy-server

I am trying to send http request through proxy server which requires authentication. Below is my code snippet. Delegate method "didReceiveChallenge" is not getting called if i am sending any "http" request but it is getting called( the "didReceiveChallenge" method) if trying with "https" request.

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()

    let proxyDict:[String:AnyObject] = [kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable as String: true,
                                        hostKey as String:proxy_server,
                                        portKey as String: proxy_port,
                                        userNameKey as String:userName,
                                        passwordKey as String:password]

   config.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict as [NSObject : AnyObject]

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        // notice that I can omit the types of data, response and error

        // your code

        print(data)
        print(error)
        print(response)

    });

    task.resume()


  //This delegate method is not getting called on "http" request. But it calls    on "https" request.
  func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge:  NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
    let credential = NSURLCredential(user:"mobiprox", password:"mobinew123", persistence: .ForSession)
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential,credential)
}
```

How can we send "http" request through proxy server which requires authentication? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to say why your problem is occurring, but I would be looking towards the server side rather than app side first and making sure that the http and https setups are equivalent and working. If you can validate that the server side is indeed correct then I would be looking to debug your code afterwards. Always ensure the services you are consuming are correct before wasting time chasing your tail in your own code only to later realise it was nothing to do with you at all :)

Comment: @dlbuckley thanks for your suggestion, as i have no knowledge in server side, so not able to get the issue. But from mobile client side my friend in android, he is able to send both http and https request on the same proxy server. So not sure if it is server side any changes required.